# Coping with number signs (hashmarks) in URLs with Ruby's URI library

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to parse a URI with Ruby's URI library. This URI contains a #.
For example, I have the URI: 
http://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/26464821879

When I call `URI.parse("http://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/26464821879").path`
"/" is returned, when I would expect to see "/#!/dhh/status/26464821879" returned.

How can I get URI.parse to properly return the path for this URI object?

Answer (score 1):

this is not the path you want, it is the [fragment](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html)

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > u = URI.parse("http://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/26464821879")
 => #<URI::HTTP:0x10071add0 URL:http://twitter.com/#!/dhh/status/26464821879> 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > u.path
 => "/" 
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > u.fragment
 => "!/dhh/status/26464821879"
```

Comment: thanks for this, this helps somewhat. I guess my concern is when you call .path with the old style Twitter URL (ie. http://twitter.com/dhh/status/26464821879) without the #! it returns what I wanted. But the #! ruins this for some reason.